# Сохранить секретный ключ в Web приложении

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, криптография

Вопрос в общем звучит так : как организовать `end-to-end` шифрование в Web приложении а конкретно - как хранить секретный ключ на стороне клиента? Предположим, сам ключ будет сгенерирован `js` в браузере пользователя, но где его хранить? Думается `Cookies` плохое решение т.к. они будут отправлены при запросе, а значит могут быть перехвачены.

Comment: `localstorage`, `indexedDB`, альтернатив не много

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для шифрования в веб есть [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).

Для сохранения данных есть [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) и [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/IndexedDB), их содержимое хранится на диске у пользователя браузера и не гуляет по сети, как куки, вместе с запросами

Comment: т.е. упрощенно процесс выглядит так : js обращается к Web Crypto API что бы сгенерировать приватный ключь и затем сохраняет его в локальное хранилище, после чего js обращается уже в `localstorage` для расшифровки сообщения ?

Comment: Согласен, что ответ был плохой. Удалил.

Comment: @Сергей да, все верно вы описали, доберусь до компьютера постараюсь запилить рабочий пример, хотя localstorage на в сниппетах stackoverflow не работает

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  если злоумышленнику удасться запустить свой скрипт в браузере он сможет достать ключ или есть ограничения на этот счет ?

Comment: @Сергей localstorage привязывается к домену, соответственно если скрипт будет запущен со страницы, которая загружена с Вашего же домена (Ваш сайт взомали) то да, доступ будет, как и у Вашего скрипта